# Block Host Name in Mysql

Tags: mysql, block, remote-access, remote-server, mysqladmin

I want to block a remote server to access MySQL and want to get this error "blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'" .

How do i block user in such manner in MySQL ? DO i need to hit the server for connection from remote server several times until it gets blocked ? Or what can be done.

Also which parameter in MySQL database does the field change when user is blocked in such case ?

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You could revoke the privileges of your users to connect from specific IPs.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'USERNAME'@'123.123.123.123';
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='USERNAME' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1');
```

If you reduce the privileges to USERNAME@localhost, only local connections are possible.
Just make sure you actually have at least one local entry (username@localhost, username@127.0.0.1, username@[local IPv6]) left, or you wont be able to login again.

make sure to apply the privileges after you change them by calling

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

To restrict the amount of connections per user@host combination, you may add additional settings to the GRANT command:

```
GRANT ALL ON customer.* TO 'USERNAME'@'123.123.123.123'
     WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0
          MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0
          MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0
          MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

More information can be found on the mysql webpage ([Setting Account Resource Limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html) and [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html))

Comment: Thanks for reply .

I had tried the revoke earlier. But that din't help.

It gave me this error "Access denied for user 'Username'@'IP Address' to database 'databaseName'" while i was trying to connect the remote server mysql.

I want the user to get this error : "blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"

Comment: I updated the answer with the settings you want: MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS. However, I wonder why you would want to do that, it solves the task with the wrong tool